# Regular Expression as basis for creating this grammar

Tags: formal-languages, automata, formal-grammars, regular-expressions

I made a right-linear grammar from a regular expression:

The alphabet is:

$Σ = \{a, b, c\} $

Regular expression:

$r = cc^{*}(ba)^{*}bb$

My solution, it seems a little too short like I'm leaving something out. Maybe someone can see where I went wrong on the right-linearity:

$ S \to cA $

$ A \to b a A | B | cA $

$ B \to bb $

Comment: did you mean $cc^*(ba)^*bb$ ?

Comment: Your solution generates $c(c+ba)^*bb$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A \rightarrow ba \mid A \mid B \mid cA$

under this $bababaccc$ is also legal

---

You could try something like this...

$S \rightarrow cS|cA$

$A \rightarrow baA|B$

$B \rightarrow bb$

Comment: +1 thanks, I also fixed the star-closure that mentioned above.  I wasn't sure about the $S \to cS | cA$ because the recursive $S$ seemed like it wouldn't be in syntax for right-linearity.  But it makes sense tho.